# LINQ List overwrites previous value instead of setting new one

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a LINQ query which outputs ToList it works fine other than the fact each time it's run it updates the original record instead of creating a new one.
On every run through this code the data.EventID changes so I'd like every record to appear in the list.

The code:

```
foreach(var data in vehicleqry)
{
 bool inUK = boundryChecker.IsLongLatInUK((double)data.declatfloat, (double)data.declongfloat);
    if (inUK == true)
    {
       var qryevent = (from e in db.events
                       where e.eventID == data.EventID
                       select new
                       {
                            e.eventID,
                            e.sysdatetime,
                            e.vehicleID
                       }).ToList();
    }
{
```

I also have a list with the eventIDs in if I can use this to query the list?
[image]

Comment: Can you explain better your issue? What do you mean by resets the index[0] values

Comment: What do you mean by resetting the index? What is `index[0]`? That doesn't exist in this code.

Comment: So every time it's run it replaces the first record instead of creating a new one

Comment: `qryevent` will only be able to initialized to a list if there are any items in your database and their `eventID` is same as `data.EventID`. Can you confirm if you have any data in your database? Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: There is data, and it gets assigned to the list. It just replaces the previous data each time instead of inserting a new record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you actually want is to only run a single query instead of looping around. You can do this by making use of the `Contains` method:

```
var vehicleqry = ...;

// Get all of the individual event IDs for entries that are "inUK"
var vehicleEventIds = vehicleqry
    .Where(ve => boundryChecker
        .IsLongLatInUK((double)ve.declatfloat, (double)ve.declongfloat)
    .Select(ve => ve.EventID);

// Get all the matching events
var qryevent = (from e in db.events
               where vehicleEventIds.Contains(e.eventID)
               select new
               {
                    e.eventID,
                    e.sysdatetime,
                    e.vehicleID
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: my bad I forgot a line of the code, the inUK part is important to filter down the eventIDs. So only when that is true do I want to add the record to the list. (updated the post with the code)

Comment: Seriously? This is why you write a good question to start with, because I've now wasted my time writing the above code.

Comment: Anyway, that can still be done by filtering the list with the `Where` clause I added.